# What is the benefit of a single input single output neural network?

Tags: regression, neural-networks

What would be the difference of a neural network with a single input and a single output with e.g. linear activation in contrast to a e.g. linear regression?

In my understanding its mathematically the same, even with a changing number of hidden layers within the nueral network. 
If so, would there still be an advantage of using a NN over using a linear regression? 
Could you confirm this assumption? Or am I on a wrong track?

Comment: Consider the case where such a neural network is used to model a simple quadratic equation: use linear regression and you are done, whereas training a neural network to the same level of accuracy would take quite a lot of work with the finished model possibly requiring much more CPU to calculate a single value.

Comment: @JamesPhillips - you might want to expand that to an answer, as it basically is.